# Send audio to trough mic

Tags: java, c#, node.js

My goal is to make an application that can play audio files "through the mic" into a skype-call (or other programs). I want to be able to speak while the audio-file is playing. Is there a simple way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve mixing audio devices with [Virtual Audio Cable](http://www.wikiwand.com/en/Virtual_Audio_Cable). You create a new Virtual Audio Cable as an input device that you can select in Skype. Then you can send audio from a specific application to your Virtual Audio Cable that will mix it with your microphone for example.

Comment: Looks like [SoundFlower](https://rogueamoeba.com/freebies/soundflower/download.php) is an alternative to Virtual Audio Cable on Mac OSX (and it's free).